# Is QQuickFramebufferItem the C++ equivalent of QML's Canvas 3D?

Tags: javascript, qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

What I want is a way to create a Qt Quick item drawn using custom OpenGL code. I seem to have found 2 ways:

- Subclass QQuickFramebufferItem and write my OpenGL code in C++
- Create a Canvas3D item in QML and draw to it from Javascript

Do these two ways really have the same purpose, with the main difference that they're used from different languages?

Comment: All QML visual item are painted using OpenGL. You just should subclass `QQuickItem` and reimplement [QQuickItem::updatePaintNode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#updatePaintNode)

Comment: @folibis: Then subclassing QQuickFramebufferItem is equivalent to subclassing QQuickItem, is it? And subclassing QQuickItem needs to be done in C++, I suppose?

Comment: Yes, `QQuickFramebufferItem` inherits from `QQuickItem`. As I understand it, `QQuickFramebufferItem` creates its content as a texture which be inserted into Scene Graph. But maybe I'm wrong. [This](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html#mixing-scene-graph-and-opengl) page can help you.

Comment: `QQuickFrameBufferItem` is a convenience adapter for rendering an item's content via OpenGL.
The ultimate base class, `QQuickItem` requires to build the item's content using the scene graph API. While this ultimately also ends up being rendered with OpenGL right now, it is a very different type of rendering to get used to.
So yes, I think the original assumption that the frame buffer item and the Canvas3D element are somewhat similar is correct.
Just like `QQuickPaintedItem` and QtQuick Canvas element being very similar in what they can do, yet doing it very differently