# Differences between Canvas3D and QQuickFramebufferObject

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

[Some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39596473) I asked whether Canvas3D and QQFBO have the same purpose. I was told they do, and I chose Canvas3D of the two, because I preferred to code in JS. But now I hit some pretty blocking problems (described at the end of [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41265492)) that led me to consider moving to QQFBO. I'm afraid QQFBO may also have limitations that are problematic for me, so my question is: **What exactly are the differences between the two?**

I know the two do basically the same thing. I know some differences:

- For Canvas3D you code in JS, for QQFBO you code in C++
- Unlike QQFBO, Every Canvas3D instance has its own OpenGL context, which takes some time to initialize, and which prevents sharing GL resources between several Canvas3Ds.
- Canvas3D puts all my GL commands in a queue and executes them later. I think this is to support multithreading, which might improve performance. Also it saves my commands for later "no-change" repaints, which might improve performance. But there's the side effect that I shouldn't use synchronous GL commands in `onPaintGL()`.
- Canvas3D is pretty buggy - [gl.colorMask and gl.depthMask break everything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40284576), [requesting GL ES 3.0 breaks everything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40408323), [gl.MULTISAMPLE is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40159793). I have hopes that QQFB will be less buggy, since it's closer to the underlying OpenGL API and since it's an older API.
- With QQFBO I think I have access to the very useful C++ GL classes of Qt such as QOpenGLShaderProgram, while with Canvas3D I have to either write plain GL code, wrap GL in my own classes (as I've done) or use something like THREE.js which has drawbacks.
- With QQFBO one has to override a `synchronize` method his QQFBO::Renderer subclass, and copy data between threads in this method. Canvas3D requires no such boilerplate.

I know of some important similarities too:

- I think both allocate a FBO and make you draw to it, instead of letting you draw directly to the window
- In Canvas3D you can fetch any QML item as an auto-updated texture, with the `createTextureFromSource()` function of the `QTCANVAS3D_texture_provider` GL extension. In QQFBO you can do the same, but with another function - `textureProvider()`.